# JavaFX special syntax

Tags: javafx, syntax

I am using JavaFX for a few months to build a professional software and I've gaps on the FXML syntax. I've seen that one-way parameters binding is possible into an FXML file using the `$` character (`${component.param}`), but I would like to know all that is possible within an FXML file :

- Is it possible to do arithmetical or logical operations using binding, like `${component1.param} + ${component2.param}` or `${component1.checked} && ${component2.checked}`?
- Is there other special characters that defines FXML parameters? I know that there is `@` and `#` but I don't know exactly when to use it.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers

Comment: Also there's `%` to access strings from resource files. Asking for explanations of `@` and `#` here would make this question too broad, but you can find those in the same document.

Comment: Thank you, I'll watch this page in detail ;)